# Minimising KL divergence between two distributions

Tags: maximum-likelihood, entropy, information-theory, kullback-leibler

Say, we want to approximate a distribution $p(x)$ with $q(x|\theta)$. We do not know the distribution $p(x)$ but we can draw samples from $p(x)$. The KL divergence between the two distributions is
$$
\begin{aligned}
KL(p\Vert q) &= -\int \ln\frac{q(x)}{p(x)}p(x)dx\\ 
\end{aligned}
$$
We can approximate the above quantity by drawing samples from $p(x)$. Replacing the above quantity with expectation, we get $$KL(p\Vert q)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N\{-\ln \,q(x_i|\theta) + \ln\,p(x_i)\}$$
Minimising this quantity with respect to $\theta$ is the same as maximising the likelihood of $q(x_i|\theta)$.

However, [Christopher Bishop](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/%7Ewurmd/Livros/school/Bishop%20-%20Pattern%20Recognition%20And%20Machine%20Learning%20-%20Springer%20%202006.pdf) writes it as just $\sum_{i=1}^N\{-\ln \,q(x_i|\theta) + \ln\,p(x_i)\}$. Shouldn't there be a $1/N$ in front ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From an optimization perspective the two are equivalent.

$\frac{1}{N}$ is just a constant that multiplies your objective function. As such, it does not affect the location of the interest points (minimums, maximums) with respect to your parameter $\theta$.