# Minimisation of KL divergence vs minimisation of empirical processes indexed by a metric space in MLE

Tags: maximum-likelihood, nonparametric, convergence, kullback-leibler, metric

I am trying to relate the interpretations of MLE as (1)minimisation of KL-divergence and (2)minimisation of empirical processes indexed by a metric space.

Questions:

1. Is it always true that maximum likelihood estimation is equivalent to the minimisation of KL divergence? (I've seen e.g., [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/498961/161649) but could there be some regularity assumptions brushed under the rug somewhere?)
2. If the goal is to maximise likelihood/minimise KL divergence, then why does one introduce indexing by a metric space? Is the idea to simplify estimation because metric spaces are nice and then hope that the limit in the topology induced by the metric also happens to be an argmin of KL divergence?
3. I see that weak convergence is used to study consistency for semi- and nonparametric maximum likelihood estimation but not for studying existence of estimators for finite samples. Why? I mean, isn't it that solving the optimisation problem for finite sample would typically require going through an optimization algorithm in a number of iterations that should in the end converge to argmax?